# Nodejs/npm: How do I resolve a path in js to a non-js resource included in my published npm package?

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface, npx

I'm building a CLI package for my webserver to publish to **npm** and download and execute using **npx**. I want to bundle a docker-compose file with the package but the code is failing to resolve the correct path to the file - it seems to try to resolve it relative to the current working directory of the shell I'm executing it from and not where the package is installed.

Example CLI node project published to as **npm** package:

```
/**
 * package name: test-cli
 * 
 * - Root project directory
 *   - docker/
 *      - docker-compose.yml
 *   - lib/
 *      - cli.js
 *   - index.js
*/

/**
 * cli.js
 */
composePath = path.resolve( // <---- running 'npx test-cli' gives error saying file not exists
  __dirname,                // terminal resolves path from where command was made
                            // instead of path of package
  "../docker/docker-compose.yml"
);
```

What is the correct way of dealing with this use-case?